# How to get the like and share button for a facebook post in javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this code for showing a like button and a share for a facebook page  :

```
<script>

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '*******',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
version: 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
       function(response) {
         alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
       }
    );

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
      function(response) {
         alert('You UNliked the URL: ' + response);
      }
    );


FB.api('/me/likes/269509429847105', function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
 alert(response.data);
});
};


(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=****";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function login(){
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');

FB.api('/me/likes/269509429847105', function(response) {
    console.log("like ?");
 alert("like ?");
    console.log(response.data);
 alert(response.data);
    console.log(response);
 alert(response);
});

     });
    } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
});
};



</script>
  <div class="loginfb">Click here to log</div>

  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <!-- Your like button code -->
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/SidAliceFreak" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" ></div>
```

It works well for a facebook page but when i try to replace the data-href in the div with the url of a facebook public post it's not working.

Does anyone know how to link a facebook public post outside facebook with it's like button ?

regards and thanks

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Since you are specifically trying to ask via API if the user likes a Facebook page called "Sid Alice Freak Artiste polyvalente", I hope you are aware that "like gating" in any form is not allowed any more. You are not allowed to show your users different content based on whether or not they liked a specific page, and neither to reward them in any other way for liking stuff.

Comment: If you actually want to show users specific posts they might have an interest in on your website, then you can use the embedded posts plugin, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts/ Users can perform a basic like directly via that if the like.

Comment: @cBroe thanks for the embeding solution